# Uncertain which driver to install. Multiple graphics controllers

Tags: linux

So I was going to install a different driver than the nouveau one but am a little uncertain whether I need the intel specific drivers for the Intel UHD Graphics 620 controller or proprietary nvidia ones for the nvidia 940mx.

output of lspci -v is:

Intel:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])    
  Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. UHD Graphics 620 
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
  Memory at ed000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable [size=16M]
  Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
  I/O ports at f000 [size=64]   [virtual]
  Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
  Capabilities: <access denied>     
  Kernel driver in use: i915    
  Kernel modules: i915
```

and the Nvidia:

```
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)
  Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 130
  Memory at ee000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
  Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
  Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
  I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
  Expansion ROM at ef000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
  Capabilities: <access denied>
  Kernel driver in use: nouveau
  Kernel modules: nouveau
```

Comment: Drivers for Intel Graphics are open-source and all desktop Linux distros I know already have them, no need for further user interaction. Nvidia is an entirely different story: `nouveau` is open-source and community driven, not Nvidia's. I may or may not work or not be enough. In that case you install the recommended Nvidia *proprietary* drivers according to your specific Nvidia chipset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Please format properly: Indent four spaces to keep the output formatted as it is. `>` is for quoting flow-text.)

Your output already says that the Kernel driver for the Intel graphics card is `i915`, while the Kernel driver for the Nvidia graphics card is `nouveau`.

So yes, you need specific drivers for both, and yes, you already installed them.

No need to change anything.